# number theory proofs with units, orders, and the phi function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do you prove the following? :

There exists some $u \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ such that for all $v \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$, $\mathrm{ord} v \mid \mathrm{ord} u$.

If the order of $u$ is $m$, then the polynomial $x^m - 1$ has $\phi(m)$ distinct roots in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $U_m$ here?

Comment: the set of all the units of $Z_m$

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem tells you the structure of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$. Can you see how that helps?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, take an element $u$ of maximal order in $U_m$. Suppose that the order of some element $t\in U_m$ has order that does not divide that of $u$. What can you say about the order of $tu$?

As written, the second part is false. Take m=5, and a maximal order element of $U_5 \simeq \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has order $4$. However, since all nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ are units, $x^3$ has only $1$ root in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand, $\phi(4) = 2$.

The statement is (typographically) close to something true: if we let $n$ be the maximal order of an element of $U_m$, the number of roots of $x^n-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is $\phi(m)$. Indeed, by choice of $n$, $a^n \equiv 1(\mod m)$ for any $a \in U_m$. To finish up, remember $|U_m| = \phi(m)$.